# Calendar Android studio (Bug?)

Tags: android, calendar

Plz, help me with the next situation. Working with android i have found a very interesting problem.
 I want use Android Calendar. I create `Calendar calendarUTC = Calendar.getInstance();` Then: `int local_hour_on_utc = calendarUTC.get(Calendar.HOUR);`. The question is: the field 'hour' is 11th at structure at calendar (i saw at debugger), but get(Calendar.HOUR) returns value of 10th field. So, it's a bug or feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start counting:
0 is 1st element in an array

1 is 2nd element in an array

2 is 3rd element in an array

..

..

..

10 is 11th element in an array

Request you to pay more attention in your programming class :)

Comment: Ofc, i know it ;) But the problem is another! May be i incorrectly described the problem. So, i show a small example.
{0 = 1
1 = 2016
2 = 2
3 = 10
4 = 1
5 = 3
6 = 63
7 = 5
8 = 1
9 = 1
10 = 6
11 = 18
12 = 7
13 = 15
14 = 656
15 = 10800000
16 = 0}
 The calendar's fields. getHour returns 6, but not a 18